# How to connect 2 routers through the internet?

Tags: network-access

I have 2 branches and I would like to connect them together through the internet they are in 2 different cities so how this work and what protocols should I use?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What are the router models?

Comment: Also, what kind of internet connection do you have for these routers or are they not connected at the moment?

Comment: And what are the specific requirements, i.e. do all device in the first branch need to communicate with all devices in the other and vice versa or do e.g. only clients in one branch need access to servers in the other?

Comment: could you please provide me more info cause i don't got it

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to connect a router to another router trough a cloud, if you say you'd like to interconnect them trough internet I am assuming you want a LAN-to-LAN connection.

For this, an IPSEC VPN is my best choice since it gives you security and privacy over a public cloud as the internet but to do that you will need a Public IP address bought on both sides of your routers

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about connecting them via Internet, but since I cant comment yet I will have to ask you here:

-Have you considered asking your ISP for a Leased Line? Its a layer 2 connection from Office A to Office B, latency will be very low and it does the job pretty well.